# Height 100% if tall, width 100% if wide

Tags: html, css

My img generates random images with random sizes sometimes tall sometimes wide. How do I make the img never bigger or smaller than the parent container? Height 100% if tall, width 100% if wide.

```
.image-container{
width: 75rem;
height: 50rem;
}

/**this does not work**/
img{
    max-width:100%;
    max-height:100%;
}
```

Comment: did you try

img{
    width: 75rem;
height: 50rem;
}

Comment: Use `width` instead: `img{ width: 100%; height: 100%; }`.

Comment: Works just fine, there must be something else.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need a little JavaScript to check the ratio of your images (if they are landscape or portrait) before you can decide to make either the height or the width to be 100%.

```js
window.onload = function() {
    let images = document.querySelectorAll("img");
    for ( let i = 0; i < images.length; i++ ) {
        images[i].width <= images[i].height ? images[i].style.height = "100%" : images[i].style.width = "100%";
    }
}
```

```css
.image-container {
    height: 300px;
    width: 500px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: floralwhite;
    border: 2px solid silver;
    margin-bottom: 2em;
}
```

```html
<div class="image-container">
    <img src="https://placehold.it/200x300">
</div>

<div class="image-container">
    <img src="https://placehold.it/600x300">
</div>

<div class="image-container">
    <img src="https://placehold.it/500x500">
</div>
```